# cann't add web part to PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout

I have created a Page Layout based on a custom Content type which inherits from Page Content Type. It contains four Custom Fields and a PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField for each field. When I try to add web parts to it it only renders html as text. why You can add web part to a PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField in BlankWebPartPage.aspx (OOB pageLayout) but it is impossible to add same web part to a custom pageLayout? thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? You're saying you "can't add webpart to" a webcontrol, but in your question you said you added the WebPart and the only problem is that it doesn't render HTML. Which one is it now? You can't add a Webpart or it renders incorrectly?

Comment: When I got Edit --> Insert --> Web Part and choose the web part and click "Add". the web part does not show up on the page. It shows some html instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding your RichHtmlField controls to asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Main" or you've created some additional placeholders?
If the second is true for you that build your master page in such a way to place the Main placeholder as the last one of used placeholders.